# Restructure nodes using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<myreport>
  <media>
    <assets>
      <asset>
        <type>image</type>
        <H>224 mm</H>
        <W>154 mm</W>
      </asset>
      <asset>
        <type>video</type>
        <H>480 px</H>
        <W>600 px</W>
      </asset>
    </assets>
</myreport>
```

I need to restructure as follows:

```
<myreport>
    <media>
        <assets>
            <image>
                <H>224 mm</H>
                <W>154 mm</W>
            </image>
            <video>
                <H>480 px</H>
                <W>600 px</W>
            <video>
        </assets>
    </media>
</myreport>
```

How do I match type with height (H) width (W) to come out with the desire transformation. I used xsl:value-of select="node" for normal restructuring.

Comment: Can you please post your XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start with the identity transformation, which copies nodes as they appear in the input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Add a special case for `asset` elements:**

```
  <xsl:template match="asset">
    <xsl:element name="{type}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note that `name={type}` will name an outputed element per the *value* of the child `type` element.

**Suppress `type` elements:**

```
  <xsl:template match="type"/>
```

**Clarify output format:**

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

**Altogether:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="asset">
    <xsl:element name="{type}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="type"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished fairly easily with a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). A template to match `asset` elements and instead of copying the `asset` element, use the value of it's type element as the name of the element to create, then apply-templates to the rest of it's children. An (empty) template that will suppress the `type` elements and any whitespace-only `text()` nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--instead of an asset element, create an element named after it's type-->
    <xsl:template match="asset[type]">
        <xsl:element name="{type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--suppress the type element and whitespace-only text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="asset/type | text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me on the last line, whats 'text()[not(normalize-space())]' for?

Comment: It is a predicate filter to match text() nodes that are nothing but white space characters. The normalize-space() function will collapse consecutive spaces, and if there is nothing but white space, returns nothing/empty, which is "falsy" in a predicate test. Using not() ensures that it is true, thus matching the white space-only text. If you remove that match expression, you would see some odd indentation in your output. You could also exclude them by altering the apply-templates to select="*" and only process child elements.